# Accessing WCF Service from Android

Tags: c#, android, wcf, xamarin

I started developing application in Android using `Xamarin` with the help of following link WCF Services accessing Android Application.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/

After everything, it is working fine in my Simulator.

But when I am connecting App from Mobile (Android 6.0), it throws `"The Operation Timeout Error"`.

Even I performed URL Reservation and firewall rule added. 
But still I am facing the error.

But I am able to connect from other PC it is working fine.

Comment: Override the default timeout limit and see if the issue is there

Comment: i tried and increase to 60 but still same issue.